# How to prevent menu from stacking on top of each other in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

When I shrink the window, I want the menu to stay on the same line as the logo in medium screen. Right now it's stacking like this [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfcNC.png). How do I fix it?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
</div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-xs">
        <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Top Authors</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
 <!--collapse navbar -->
```

Comment: Assign `display: inline-block` to your `.navbar-header` on the medium screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say because there is no CSS posted, but you can generally use `inline-block` to position the elements on the same line. Roughly:

```
.navbar-header {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:30%;
  text-align:left;
}
.nav {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:65%;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: I haven't wrote anything on my CSS file yet. This is purely coming from Bootstrap. I also tried using inline-block but it didn't work :/. I managed to make the Login link to be on the same line as the Logo and but the sign up link kept being push down below

Comment: yes sorry that's because both `ul` elements are currently sharing the class `nav`. You should wrap both `ul` elements in a `div` with the class `wrap`, then the above code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe due to some discrepancy in adhering to bootstrap standard navbar. Below is a snippet implementing your code, but I applied it to the template provided in the [Bootstrap navbar documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar), please let me know if you face any issues.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-xs">
        <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Top Authors</a></li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I don't want the Login and Sign Up links to collapse. I just want it to stay on the same line as the Logo.